# Group by query and SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have this query

```
select SUM(Qty) as Qty
from WorkTbl  group by Status
having Status = 'AA' or Status = 'BB'
```

this query returns 2 rows (100 and 500)

How to sum those 2 rows ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take out the `GROUP BY`, and use `WHERE` instead of `HAVING`?

```
select SUM(Qty) as Qty
from WorkTbl
where Status = 'AA' or Status = 'BB'
```

Or, if there's more to your query, and you wish to keep most of the current structure, put it into a subquery (or a CTE):

```
select SUM(Qty) from (
select SUM(Qty) as Qty
from WorkTbl  group by Status
having Status = 'AA' or Status = 'BB'
) t
```

(We have to include the `t` at the end, since every row source in the from clause has to have a name - it could be anything)